How to get booktabs styling with Typst
I am trying to get the booktabs looks from LaTeX in Typst. This includes, among other things, rules of a certain weight and tighter spacing between rows. Is there a Typst package that implements this?
I have tried to recreate parts of the looks myself. Rules can be implemented both as strokes for certain rows or as table.hline:
#show table: set align(center)

// rules as table.hline
#table(
  columns: 3,
  align: (left, center, center),
  stroke: none,
  table.hline(stroke: 0.08em),
  table.header(
    [Substance],
    [Subcritical \ °C],
    [Supercritical \ °C],
  ),
  table.hline(stroke: 0.05em),
  [Hydrochloric Acid],
  [12.0], [92.1],
  [Sodium Myreth Sulfate],
  [16.6], [104],
  [Potassium Hydroxide],
  table.cell(colspan: 2)[24.7],
  table.hline(stroke: 0.08em),
)

// rules as strokes
#set table(
  stroke: (x, y) => if y == 0 {
    (bottom: 0.05em + black, top: 0.08em)
  } else if y == 3 {
    (bottom: 0.08em)
  }
)

#table(
  columns: 3,
  align: (left, center, center),
  table.header(
    [Substance],
    [Subcritical \ °C],
    [Supercritical \ °C],
  ),
  [Hydrochloric Acid],
  [12.0], [92.1],
  [Sodium Myreth Sulfate],
  [16.6], [104],
  [Potassium Hydroxide],
  table.cell(colspan: 2)[24.7],
)


However, when I try to implement the tighter row and line spacing, neither solution performs particularly well:
#set table(row-gutter: -0.5em)
#show table: set par(leading: .15em)


Any suggestions to mitigate this? Of course, a booktabs package implementation in Typst would be even greater.

It's not quite the same as booktabs, but it might be worth exploring tablex?

Thanks for the pointer! On the GitHub page, it encourages users to use built-in Typst tables instead of tablex so I haven't had a closer look yet.

#set table(inset: ...) might be what you want. Let me know, then I'll type up an answer.

I think that's it! Thank you so much. I will try eyeballing the booktabs look but for a start, #set table(inset: (top: 0.3em, bottom: 0.3em)) doesn't feel too bad.

To fully recreate the booktabs looks it seems that table.hline() would have to have its own "gutter", as described here: https://github.com/typst/typst/issues/4743
